# chrome shows passwords regardless of keyring locked or unlocked

Tags: google-chrome, password

My concern is that chrome shows the saved passwords in chrome://settings/passwords regardless whether i have locked or unlocked the login keyring. i also tried to change my login keyring to something different than my login password to ubuntu.  I feel uncomfortable with this setup, I figure chrome should only show the passwords when I unlock the keyring, no?